# Что не поддерживается в Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, тестирование

Вопрос из теста по obj-c:

> Что не поддерживается в Objective-C?
>
> - Рекурсивный вызов метода
> - Переменное количество аргументов у метода
> - Байтовые манипуляции
> - Дефолтное значение аргумента метода
> - Ничего из выше перечисленного

В ответе может быть более одного верного. Как понимаю это "Переменное количество аргументов у метода" но может ли быть еще вариант "Дефолтное значение аргумента метода"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дефолтное значение аргумента метода не поддерживаются, байтовые операции поддерживаются в с, а значит и в obj-c как имеющем с ним полную совместимость, а по рекурсии - достаточно один раз в наследнике в методе по ошибке дернуть [self method] вместо [super method] и наличие рекурсии как-то само собой запоминается :).

Правда оба финта можно реализовать через введение нескольких функций все из которых будут вызывать наиболее полный вариант с пустыми значениями или со значениями по умолчанию типа

```
-(id) init{
     return [self initWithFrame:CGRectNull];
}
```

**UPD**
Переменное количество аргументов у метода можно осуществить через [va_list](http://oxigen-objectivec.blogspot.ru/2009/04/nsstring-stringwithformat.html)

Comment: Про рекурсию, это да)  За остальное спасибо - весьма познавательно!

Comment: >> Переменное количество аргументов у метода не поддерживаются

Здесь считают иначе: http://idev.by/ios/snippets/8189/

Comment: у меня антивирь на нее ругается

Comment: @aknew, ты б постеснялся такое вслух произносить. Переменное количество аргументов поддерживается. Или никогда NSLog не юзал? arrayWithObjects?

Comment: да я уже и сам сообразил, даже отписал через что оно делается в комменте к другому вопросу :( Ща ответ исправлю чтобы народ в заблуждение не вводить

Answer (score 4):

Дефолтное значение аргумента метода. [Ответ по первой ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871796/objective-c-default-argument-value) в выдаче по запросу ["default argument values in objective c"](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=default%2Bargument%2Bvalues%2Bin%2Bobjective%2Bc&oq=default%2Bargument%2Bvalues%2Bin%2Bobjective%2Bc).

Comment: только это два разных метода, а не дефолтное значение, так что именно на вопрос поддерживается ли дефолтное значение ответ нет. Хотя может переменное число значений и можно протащить через сишный va_list

Comment: >> только это два разных метода, а не дефолтное значение

Это к чему относится?

>> так что именно на вопрос поддерживается ли дефолтное значение ответ нет

Вопрос был "что из перечисленного не поддерживается", а не "что поддерживается".

Comment: "Это к чему относится?"

к -(id)myFunction:(NSArray*)array {
  return [self myFunction:array withSort:FALSE];
} из первой ссылки

Comment: Гм, значит хитрый яндекс подсовывает разные результаты.
Я имел в виду это:

No, default arguments are a feature of C++, not C or Objective-C

(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871796/objective-c-default-argument-value)

Comment: нет, яндекс тут не причем - это я не увидел этого ответа, он у меня в самом низу стоит. В общим, имели мы в виду одно и то же :)